# How return to the same page of UIViewPager in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using [CAPSPageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) in order to create ViewPager in my ios app. One of my page in ViewPager is TableView. When I click on the cell of TableView I go to another controller. But when I return I go to the FIRST page of ViewPager, but I tapped 3rd page. How can I return to the same page of my ViewPager, not the start? Here I goes to ViewController from 3rd page of ViewPager:

```
  let destination = ConcreteSupportPlanViewController() // Your destination
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I put all stuff for initialization into

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

Instead

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```